# PHP Creating New Class Instance Stops Page from Loading (CentOS)

Tags: php, class, centos, xampp

I created a PHP login portal in a local computer running XAMPP v1.8.2-3 and it was working fine, but when I uploaded it in a CentOS 6.6 (Final) which I also use for other PHP stuff, it was not working at all.

I noticed that when right after I create a new class instance "$user = new User()" the page will stop loading with no errors.

I am I missing a package or something?

```
php.i686                5.3.3-46.el6_6    @updates
php-cli.i686            5.3.3-46.el6_6    @updates
php-common.i686         5.3.3-46.el6_6    @updates
php-mysql.i686          5.3.3-46.el6_6    @updates
php-pdo.i686            5.3.3-46.el6_6    @updates
php-xml.i686            5.3.3-46.el6_6    @updates
mysql.i686              5.1.73-3.el6_5    @base
mysql-libs.i686         5.1.73-3.el6_5    @anaconda-CentOS-201410241409.i386/6.6
mysql-server.i686       5.1.73-3.el6_5    @base
httpd.i686              2.2.15-39.el6.centos
httpd-tools.i686        2.2.15-39.el6.centos
```

Code:

```
require_once('core/init.php');

echo "before $user = new user()";

$user = new user();

echo "After $user = new user()";

<form action="" method="post">
</form>
```

Browser Result:

```
before $user = new user()
```

Comment: Your server log will tell you what's exactly wrong. We can't. We can only guess.

Comment: Add some sort of error reporting to the top of your file... such as
    `error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'on');`

Comment: Have you checked if the PHP version is the same? Do you have access to any error log?

Comment: @chris72205 Definitely a "no" for production sites, better to setup a custom error log file.

Comment: @Cranio for debugging something like this, it's an acceptable thing to do

Comment: @chris72205 There are many companies where this bad practice is really, really far less than "acceptable", I can guarantee it. It depends on the context you work in, and in any case I always suggest a good practice.

Comment: @Cranio this code is clearly not in production.  He is echoing out markers before and after a statement, so temporarily putting error reporting on his page to debug this issue will help him figure out the cause of his problem quicker (and easier.)  I do agree that using an error log is the correct way to do things in a production environment.